# TTreeView in Inno Setup

Tags: treeview, inno-setup, pascal

I'd like to add a treeview control to a page in my installer and have searched the [inno setup help](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses) for a `TTreeView` class, but only found `TFolderTreeView` and `TStartMenuFolderTreeView` which is not what I need to have. Do I have to use a `TListBox` or something similiar instead? Or is there an extension for that?

---

I even created a type hierarchy tree for predefined types:

```
class
    TObject
        TPersistent
            TComponent
                TControl
                    TWinControl
                        TCustomControl
                            TCustomPanel
                                TPanel
                            TNewNotebookPage
                        TScrollingWinControl
                            TForm
                                TUIStateForm
                                    TSetupForm
                                        TMainForm
                                        TWizardForm
                                        TUninstallProgressForm
                        TCustomEdit
                            TEdit
                                TNewEdit
                            TCustomMemo
                                TMemo
                                    TNewMemo
                                    TRichEditViewer
                            TPasswordEdit
                        TCustomComboBox
                            TComboBox
                                TNewComboBox
                        TButtonControl
                            TButton
                                TNewButton
                            TCustomCheckBox
                                TCheckBox
                                    TNewCheckBox
                            TRadioButton
                                TNewRadioButton
                        TCustomListBox
                            TListBox
                                TNewListBox
                            TNewCheckListBox
                        TNewStaticText
                        TNewProgressBar
                        TCustomFolderTreeView
                            TFolderTreeView
                            TStartMenuFolderTreeView
                        TNewNotebook
                TGraphicControl
                    TCustomLabel
                        TLabel
                    TBevel
                    TBitmapImage
                TWizardPage
                    TInputQueryWizardPage
                    TInputOptionWizardPage
                    TInputDirWizardPage
                    TInputFileWizardPage
                    TOutputMsgWizardPage
                    TOutputMsgMemoWizardPage
                    TOutputProgressWizardPage
            TStrings
                TStringList
            TGraphicsObject
                TFont
                TPen
                TBrush
            TCanvas
            TGraphic
                TBitmap
        TStream
            THandleStream
                TFileStream
            TStringStream
procedure
    TNotifyEvent
    TCloseEvent
    TCloseQueryEvent
    TKeyEvent
    TKeyPressEvent
    TFolderRenameEvent
    TWizardPageNotifyEvent
    TWizardPageCancelEvent
enum
    TFontStyle
    TPenMode
    TPenStyle
    TBrushStyle
    TAlign
    TScrollBarKind
    TFormBorderStyle
    TBorderIcon
    TPosition
    TCloseAction
    TEShiftState
    TAlignment
    TEditCharCase
    TScrollStyle
    TComboBoxStyle
    TCheckBoxState
    TListBoxStyle
    TBevelShape
    TBevelStyle
    TPanelBevel
    TCheckItemOperation
    TNewProgressBarState
    TNewProgressBarStyle
set
    TFontStyles
    TBorderIcons
    TShiftState
alias
    TScrollBarInc
    TBorderStyle
    TBevelWidth
    TBorderWidth
function
    TWizardPageButtonEvent
    TWizardPageShouldSkipEvent
```

Comment: In fact, I thought of implementing a `TNewCheckListBox` at first, too. For my use case I only need a treeview of node depth of 2, so I'll better go with a `TComboBox` or a `TNewNotebook` for grouping and then add some sort of list, depending on the selected group.

Comment: I talked with my advisor and our company will move away from InnoSetup as having too few skilled people in pascal. It isn't worth putting effort into something which is poorly understood. I will close the question and look for alternatives.

- Thank you for your help & patience -

Comment: Please remove the `《Closed》` from your title. It's already displayed next to the question in every list, and adds no meaning to the question.

Comment: The next time I will better invest my time. Good to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact such component.

I think it is much easier (and faster) to write your component in Delphi and use it in Inno Setup as plug-in (.dll file).

Comment: Delphi is the Best! :)

Comment: I would rather say *was* the best :)